# Taylor expansion of the square of the distance function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

Give a smooth Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, (i) how can one compute Taylor expansion of the square of the Riemannian distance function $d^2(x,x_0)$ at $(x',x_0)$?

I've tried to use $dist=\int (g_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{dt} \frac{dx^\nu}{dt} )^{1/2} dt$ to expand $dist^2$, but it was so messy. BTW, I've found that a similar question has been asked at [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215573/square-of-the-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold). The answer given is actually very nice but it goes a little too technical and quite cryptic to me... In particular, the final result seems to a generalised Cosine law, right?!

(ii) Doesn't it make a sense to write $d^2(x,x_0)=d^2(x'+(x-x'),x_0)$ and take it as a scalar function?! Under what conditions can one assume that the square of the distance function is a polynomial?

I would appreciate answers not demanding an all profound background...

Comment: Just a comment: to be able to write $d^2(x, x_0) = d^2(x' + (x-x'), x_0)$ you must have a structure of linear space on your manifold which is not always the case. I don't know whether it can be fixed via charts/atlases in general case or not.

Comment: Dear @Evgeny what do you mean by a structure of linear space?!

Comment: When you write $x' + (x-x')$ (points $x$ and $x'$ are from manifold $M$), you must know what $x+y$ means for two points of manifold and what $\alpha \cdot x$ when $\alpha$ is a scalar from some field. If you have a meaningful definition of these two operations for your manifold (of course, with some additional properties), then you have vector (or linear) space structure on $M$.

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah..I get your points.. I think one can locally define $x+x'$ with a diffeomorphism $ f: M\to R^n$...however, If I understand it correctly, one need to use the exponential map for a global structure..

Comment: I can't say anything deeper than this little observation. You need someone more experienced in differential geometry or topology to say how "Riemannian vector space" looks like and what are possible options :)